# Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly MYSQL, Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: mysql, windows-services, innodb, windows-server-2008-r2, mysql-backup

OS : **Windows Server 2008 R2**
MYSQL : **MY SQL Server 5.6**

ERROR :

```
2015-04-02 14:31:52 2956 [ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2015-04-02 14:31:52 2956 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2015-04-02 14:31:52 2956 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-04-02 14:31:52 2956 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-04-02 14:31:52 2956 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-04-02 14:31:52 2956 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Steps Tried :

```
 1. Deleted ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 and checked.
 2. Edited my-default.ini
basedir="C:\mysql-5.6.11-win32\"
datadir="C:\mysql-5.6.11-win32\data\"
port=3306
server-id=1
bind-address=127.0.0.1

**Current files/folders in Mysql/data**:

WIN-BVVOL64R2ST.pid

WIN-BVVOL64R2ST.err

ibdata1

auto.CNF

performance_schema and

mysql
```

Need help to fix this, very much important.
And please let me know how can i take backup if **MySQL service** is not running.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode

implies a permission problem, either on that file, or on the directory it is in.

Changing `basedir` will lose track of `ibdata1`, hence should be used with caution.